# question about complex analysis log function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this domain:

$$D = \{z \in\Bbb C: \text{Re}(z) \leq \text{Im}(z) < \text{Re}(z) + 2\pi\}.$$

We know that the exponential function restricted to D is one-to-one

The log is defined as: Log: C - {0} ---> C

And the question is:

Define log as the corresponding inverse function. Is so define log continuous at all points of its domain?

I was thinking about how to prove and I think I have to prove that is compact, i.e. that is closed and bounded, and I think it is, but I don't really know how to make this proof.

Comment: $z=0$ is in the domain, and $\log(z)$ blows up there and hence is not continuous.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson Logarithm, being the inverse function, is defined on $\exp(D)$, which does not contain $0$.

Comment: But we definde the log : C\{0}--> C

Comment: @louis Logarithm does not have a single-valued holomorphic branch on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$. In plain terms, there is no continuous function $f:\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb C$ such that $\exp(f(z))=z$. ¶ If you insist that you have $\log$ defined on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$, you should explain *how* it is defined.

Comment: the function is define as: exp: C --->  C∖{0} where every point w in C∖{0} has infinitely many pre-images under exp.  
 And then log(z):= exp^-1(z)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the restriction of the exponential function to $D$. As you observed, $f$  is injective on $D$. Therefore, it has the inverse function $f^{-1}:f(D)\to D$.

However, the inverse function is not continuous. The problem is that $f$ "glues" two sides of the infinite strip $D$ together. For example, $f(0)=1$ and $\lim_{y\to 2\pi-}f(iy)=1$. Therefore, in any neighborhood of $1\in f(D)$ the inverse function $f^{-1}$ will attain value $0$, as well as some values close to $2\pi i$. This implies that   $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.